# Apache Zeppelin - Date Picker

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have connected Zeppelin to MySQL database.
I can retrieve the data, but have a problem.
How to create SQL in Zeppelin that allow user to retrieve the data by choosing the date range?

Answer (score 2):

1. Zeppelin doesn't have a "date picker". It has input fields and select dropdown boxes
2. AFAIK, [you cannot use form inputs with JDBC interpreters](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/manual/dynamicform.html#using-form-templates). Only Markdown, Shell, and Spark

It might be possible to add an AngularJS widget that somehow gave you two way binding to interpreter variables, it's just not provided out of the box

Comment: you can set variable in angular and use it with `z.get` `z.put` from angular pyspark and spark

Comment: Right, but it's not a calendar-like datepicker

Answer (score -2):

Dynamic form works in JDBC interpreter.

`select ${num=1, 1(one)|2(two)} as num, ${date='2018-02-14'}::DATE as date`

[image: jdbc dynamic form]

Comment: This is not a datepicker!